# xcconfig files device families - universal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcconfig

I am changing the name of my app based on the device it is running on through configuration files, i.e. I put in an _iPhone, _iPad or _Universal in the display name accordingly.

To do this I am using xcconfig files as follows:

```
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1,2

APP_NAME1 = Something_iPhone
APP_NAME2 = Something_iPad
APP_NAME1,2 = Something_Universal //1,2 The "," causes a problem here.
```

The problem is that the comma character is causing a problem:
  *Build setting 'APP_NAME1,2' does not have a valid base name.*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No apps will be approved for app store with using the trade marked names such as iPhone or iPad try using something else. I have had that even in the binary and not in the display and they rejected it in review. If you want to create a set of codes for universal porpose the take a look at this code snippet. I use this a lot in my universal apps.

```
`if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    NSLog(@"iPad Idiom"); 
else
#else
    NSLog(@"iPhone Idiom");
#endif
```

Adrian

Comment: Thanks Adrian, but the question here isn't as much about the name as it is about the problem with the setting name.

Comment: I was under the impression that you want your code to be universal. So I did edit my answer. Sorry if I misunderstood you. Keep the question open and one of the moderators will offer alternative.